# Модальное окно появляется позже загрузки DOM

Tags: dom, атрибуты

[Есть сайт с обоями](https://wallpapershome.com/nature/) , спустя определенное время, там выскакивает модалка с тем, чтобы отключить adblock. Есть расширение для chrome user css и js, которое позволяет применять юзер js и css к странице. рименяется к DOM, когда он загружен. Туда в графу JS прописываю следующее document.querySelector('.adblock').removeAttribute('style'), но атрибут не удаляется, почему так происходит? Если это же прописать в консоли панели разработчика в chrome, то все срабоает, так как там весь DOM уже подгружен

Смотрел... Сам див с adblock подгружается позже загрузки основного DOM. Пытался через DOMContentLoaded... Не получилось. Как быть?

[image: user CSS and JS]

[image: модалка]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ, как можно отслеживать изменение DOM. MutationObserver

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    mutation.target.removeAttribute('style')
  });
});

mutationObserver.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true
});
```

Спасибо тем, кто пытался помочь